# Diagonally dominant matrix for Cholesky?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, factoring, symmetric-matrices, cholesky-decomposition

I have a $10^6 \times 10^6$ dense SPD matrix, which I am called to invert, by using Cholesky factorization.

However, I came across this statement:

> We start with the Cholesky and LU decompositions, which work only with positive definite and nonsingular diagonally dominant square matrices, respectively (Sects. 4.1.1 and 4.1.2).

[Source](http://sfb649.wiwi.hu-berlin.de/fedc_homepage/xplore/ebooks/html/csa/node36.html)

If I go to the relevant section, I see nothing relevant. I hadn't thought of the diagonally dominant property, should I?

Comment: Indeed. The right question is what machines. However, "they" insist that an inversion must be performed, thus I think that Cholesky is the way to go. @AlgebraicPavel

Comment: If you want to compute factors for such a large matrix, I would suggest you lookup "out-of-core Cholesky factorization" or so. It might take, however, months to compute it on a desktop.

Comment: I agree. What does out of core means @AlgebraicPavel?

Comment: @G.Samaras, do you really need to invert it ? Is it used to solve a linear system ?

Comment: [OOC algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-core_algorithm) are designed for problems which do not fit to main memory and use additional (slower but of high capacity) level of the memory hierarchy such as hard drive(s).

Comment: @Michael I would love not to. Yes and they said they have tried many things, but they did not work. For that reason, they want me to do the inversion. If it very broad for a comment to explain the problem.. Thanks Pavel!

Comment: Have they tried the conjugate gradient method ?

Comment: @Michael I do not think so, since the matrix is dense. They have tried iterative methods, but the preconditioner was not good enough, since the matrix they want to invert is ill conditioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyword here is "respectively". Cholesky works with positive definite, and LU works with diagonally dominant.

Comment: Oh yeah, but I also saw that: "That is a huge matrix, and you may need to be careful: unless your matrix is almost diagonally dominant, you may have stability problems inverting that large of a matrix with Cholesky!", so I am still a bit worried...